# Use the AzureCLI task to delete containers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage

I know that `az storage blob delete-batch` lets you delete blobs from a blob container recursively. I need to delete *containers* instead of single blobs. In particular, I need to delete containers older than two years. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, there're two parts to your problem:

1. **Deleting Multiple Containers**: For this you can write a script that will first list the containers using [`az storage container list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-container-list), loop over that list to delete each container individually using [`az storage container delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-container-delete).
2. **Find Containers Older Than 2 Years**: This is going to be a tricky thing because currently there's no way to find out when a blob container was created. It does have a `Last Modified Date` property but that gets changed every time an operation is performed on that blob container (not including the operations performed on the blobs inside that container).

Comment: Does not the `--if-unmodified-since` parameter automatically delete all the appropriate containers? Do I need to iterate?

Comment: It's blob container's modified date. You could have a container that was created 5 years ago but then you performed an operation (say change it's metadata) and that changes the last modified date. You may very well blobs in there which are there for more than 2 years.

Comment: And yes, you would need to iterate over blob containers.

Comment: So it is unsafe to use that parameter. So, what should I prefer?

Comment: Is your storage account v2? I may have an alternate approach.

Comment: In reality, I don't own the account, I only work on it, so I don't know.

Comment: Your objective is eventually clean up the container if the blobs in that container have not been modified for over two years. Right?

Comment: Yes. The Blob Storage will contain several containers, whose names will be kind of `build#=...Year=...`. I don't want to keep the builds older than 2 years. I don't think the builds will ever be modified, so I think their metadata will stay the same forever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208653/discussion-between-franco-scarpa-and-gaurav-mantri).